# Validation with KendoUI datetime

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

Hi i have an app where user can select for start datetime and end datetime if they want to create an event.
Now this is an html where i use KendoUI datetime plugin:

```
<div class="demo-section" style="width: 535px;">
                <label for="start">Start date:</label>
                <input id="start" value="01/01/2013" />

                <label for="end" style="margin-left:3em">End date:</label>
                <input id="end" value="01/01/2013"/>
            </div>
</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

function startChange() {
    var startDate = start.value();
    if (startDate) {
        startDate = new Date(startDate);
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate());
        end.min(startDate);
    }
}

function endChange() {
    var endDate = end.value();

    if (endDate) {
        endDate = new Date(endDate);
        endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate());
        start.max(endDate);
    }
}

var start = $("#start").kendoDateTimePicker({
    change: startChange,
    parseFormats: ["MM/dd/yyyy"]
}).data("kendoDateTimePicker");

var end = $("#end").kendoDateTimePicker({
    change: endChange,
    parseFormats: ["MM/dd/yyyy"]
}).data("kendoDateTimePicker");

start.max(end.value());
end.min(start.value());

});
```

Issues is i cant get validation as i want. Suppose user select `From` date the `To` date should display date which is greater that currently selected `From` date.My currrent code seems not works well. Thanks

Comment: Works fine, check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/meM5T/1/. What does not work? Which date do you select for `From`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying that you want to be able to select a `From` date greater than `To`, and that when you do `To` should automatically update to be greater than `From`?

If so you're almost there. You just need to update the `startChange` function to update the `To` date relative to `From`.

```
function startChange() {
    var startDate = start.value();
    if (startDate) {
        startDate = new Date(startDate);
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate());
        end.min(startDate);
        var endDate = end.value();
        if (endDate && endDate <= startDate) {
            endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
            end.value(endDate);
        }
    }
}
```

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nukefusion/meM5T/4/) for a full working example.